# Rationale behind Haskells `succ` on numbers (floats)

Tags: haskell, floating-point, enumerable

I was a bit surprised to learn that Haskell defines its `succ` function on numbers as adding one:

> `succ :: a -> a`
>   The successor of a value. For numeric types, succ adds **1**.

Although for integral values, this seems reasonable there are a few problems:

- what if you define a numeric system that can only represent even/odd/prime/... numbers, in other words a dedicated type that is a subset of integral numbers;
- if you define some kind of "fixed-point number" that represents half and full numbers, in that case not all numbers are enumerated; and
- the problem is most severe for **floating point numbers**.

First of all, it means that `[2.0 :: Float .. 3.0 :: Float]` (used `:: Float` to make sure the call is not ambiguous) only contains integral values added to the original value, whereas if one uses this expression he/she might expect the list will include all floating points between the two values; of course this argument is more about what one prefers. Most programmers don't have much problems with this aspect.

More severely, if one uses the expression `[2.2 :: Float .. 4.0 :: Float]` it results in `[2.2,3.2,4.2]` what is **`4.2`** doing here?

If one uses a floating point number where `+1` cannot generate a different number (because the mantissa doesn't have enough bits to represent one anymore), it will loop infinitely. For instance:

```
Prelude> [1e37 :: Float .. 1e37 :: Float]
[1.0e37,1.0e37,1.0e37,1.0e37,1.0e37,1^C.0e37,Interrupted.
Prelude> [1e37 :: Float .. 1e37-1 :: Float]
[1.0e37,1.0e37,1.0e37,1.0e37,1.0e37,1^C.0e37,Interrupted.
Prelude> [1e37 :: Float .. 1e37+1 :: Float]
[1.0e37,1.0e37,1.0e37,1.0e37,1.0e37,1^C.0e37,Interrupted.
Prelude> [1e37 :: Float .. pred 1e37 :: Float]
[1.0e37,1.0e37,1.0e37,1.0e37,1.0e37,1^C.0e37,Interrupted.
```

One thus generates an infinite amount of values, even if the list ought to be empty or contain a few elements.

Part of the arguments are indeed a bit nitpicking, but at least for some, it is reasonable to assume that a Haskell programmer will eventually make mistakes.

Wouldn't a more reasonable approach have been to generate the next representable floating point number?

What were the arguments to define `succ` in such way? Is it reasonable that `Float` is an instance of `Enum`?

Comment: Floating points `[x..y]` intervals are IMHO inherently flawed -- there's no sane way to define them. Having that list all the floats between `x` and `y` would be interesting but not very useful in practice (how often would one use that?). Having one-stepped lists as we have now exposes to rounding errors, causing `[1.0 .. 100.0]` to end with `99` if `1+1+...` happens to be `100+epsilon` due to rounding errors (it does not, but if we replace `100` with a large enough number..). The "solution" adopted by Haskell considers `4.2` as `4.0+epsilon` so that it is included in the list. (`epsilon~0.5`)

Comment: @chi: yes, and that last aspect (`4.2`=`4+e`) is the problematic part I think. As said in the question, it's not that bad that it iterates over adding integrals. But one would expect the range to end before (or at) the limit. It would probably have been better that `Float` would not be an `instance` of `Enum`... One can still emulate it with `map (\x -> fromIntegral x + 0.2) [0..4]` after all...

Comment: @chi: Listing all floating-point numbers in a range is fairly useful, at least for 32-bit floats.  For instance, you can test a function's correctness for all floats in some range.

Comment: @tmyklebu OK, but do you think that would be used so commonly in practice to deserve a special syntax `[x..y]`? I can see this being available as a library function, instead.

Comment: @chi: I'm not really a Haskell user and I'm probably not representative of users of anything in specific, so I'd rather not make a statement of that sort.  I do use this quite a bit when I'm doing something fiddly enough that I don't want to be wrong.

Comment: @CommuSoft Agreed. However, "iterates over adding integrals" fits badly in the (troublesome) numeric hierarchy of Haskell. Adding can be performed only in the same type (no ints + floats), so you need a conversion somewhere. Further, if `x,y::Float` how do you choose how many integrals to add for `[x..y]`? Would you use `floor(y-x)`? If so, we have rounding issues (`[1.0..10.0-eps]`). If we use `round(y-x)` we sometimes get a "too large" element as the `4.2` before. :-(

Comment: @CommuSoft Don't get me wrong -- I can see choosing `floor(y-x)` leading to a useful result (which is at least guaranteed to lie between extremes). The Haskell committee roughly chose `round(y-x)` instead, probably worrying that `[1.0 .. x]` where `x` was evaluating to `10.0` with some very small error should have exactly `10` elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The origin of the `succ` function itself actually has nothing to do with the Haskell data types or enumerations, in fact the `succ` function came first.  The `succ` function is actually the ***successor*** function in the [***axiom of infinity***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity) which allows us to [create numbers in the first place](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers).  It was never designed to be used with floating point/non-natural numbers, that's why you're encountering this problem.

It would probably be a good idea to modify the `succ` function for floating point types in Haskell, you ought to submit something to the mailing list about it.  Although, Haskell is standardized in the Haskell98 report so don't get your hopes up about changing the language.

**Only read the following if you are familiar with Haskell's type classes:** You mention different possible uses of the `succ` function, this is why it is defined as a function for the `Enum` type class.  Therefore you can easily rebind it to do something different with a `newtype`.

Comment: I'm indeed familiar with Haskell's typeclasses and it is indeed reasonable to use a `FloatEnum` typeclass, although the `Enum` is used in a lot of utility classes, thus one would expect the design of standard classes to be done extremely careful.

Comment: @CommuSoft I completely agree with that rational, that's why I encourage you to submit something to one of the mailing lists.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that `succ` can have a similar-to-identical progeny in a type-theoretic foundation as well in the type theoretic definition of the natural numbers. The latter might be more natural to a system like Haskell.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson Possibly, although I am not familiar enough with type-theory to confidently post an answer using it.